# How can I find genes of fundamental metabolic processes for an organism?

Tags: sequence-alignment, gene, blast, phylogenetics, sequence-homology

I want to find genes of fundamental metabolic processes in the *Phytophthora cinnamomi* genome. I'm using the genome sequence deposited in the NCBI and I'm searching ORF by ORF, using the ORF finder (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/orffinder/). Next, I use SMARTBLAST (https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/smartblast/?LINK_LOC=BlastHomeLink) to find similar organisms. 
How do I know that the gene that I'm searching expresses proteins of fundamental metabolic processes, and if the organism is similar to mine?
Can the best hits in SMARTBLAST tell me something about that?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please not SHOUT?

Comment: Should be a bit quiter now ;)